# Android FragmentManager calls onCreateView while clearing fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have these methods for fragment manipulation:

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack) {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame, fragment);
    if (addToBackStack) {
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName());
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
}

public void clearFragments() {
    if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        FragmentManager.BackStackEntry first = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(0);
        fragmentManager.popBackStack(first.getId(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }
}
```

Scenario:

I start with fragment A, when activity is created. **addFragment(new A, false);**

Then I add fragment B. **replaceFragment(new B);**

I add another fragment C. **addFragment(new C);**

In C fragment I want to reset application to A fragment. I call **clearFragments(); addFragment(new A, false);**

The problem is that B fragment `onCreateView` is called after pressing button on C fragment that clears fragments and adds A fragment. I don't see the fragment, but it starts background thread that crashes my app. I need to clear all fragments without calling their `onCreateView()` methods.

Is this expected behaviour, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually in such a scenario you will always return to the fragment B.

Step by step:

1. Adding A.
2. Replacing A with B <- after this step you don't have A within your activity.
3. Adding C. Here you are adding another fragment and telling FragmentManager to preserve current state of fragments to the back stack. Your current state at this point is fragment B. Then fragment C is added.
4. When you call clearFragments, FragmentManager returns to the first saved state - and this state is fragment B.

Maybe you forgot to mention something? I tried to put several entries in a back stack and then reset to the first state - onCreateView is called once, only for the first fragment.

Comment: How can I clear all fragments without returning to first saved state, so in the application I would see empty space where R.id.main_frame is?

Comment: You can make a call to addToBackStack for you first fragment - A. Instead of addFragment(new A(), false) -> addFragment(new A(), true). So, your first state will be empty container.

Comment: If you want to preserve your back stack, you can just manually remove all fragments.

Comment: Changing `addFragment(new A, false);` to `addFragment(new A, true);` didn't helped. Same situation happens. I return to fragment B after clearing fragments.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that replaceFragment should have addToBackStack call as well. Without it your back stack chain is not full. Can you please add it and check again?

Comment: But then it wouldn't count as replacement. I have few fragments that are not supposed to stack on top but rather replace each other, so that by pressing back user would only see one of these fragments, not whole history of them.

Comment: Unfortunately Back Stack just reproduces your saved actions in reversed order. If you put only B->C replacement there (this is exactly what you are doing in addFragment(new C(), true)), then after pressing Back it will reverse that actions to C->B: it will remove C and add B. Let's try to find another way to do what you want. Can you explain what exactly you are trying to create?

Comment: I just want to be able to add fragment (with ability to go back by pressing back), replace current fragment with different one, and clear all fragments. Also I need to be able to add fragment without adding it to backstack, so back button would return to last entry in bakcstack or quit app. Maybe I can implement replace method somehow clearing last entry and adding new one?

Comment: In your scenario, fragment B is the fragment you don't want to put in back stack, right? A and C should be in back stack?

Comment: Not really, I don't ever want to come back to A fragment by pressing back. And instead of B fragment, there could be B1 and B2 fragments that are replaced interchangeably with one another and I don't want to have this change history recorded in back stack, so only the last of them should be in back stack. C must be in back stack.

Comment: Thanks for the information, with it I managed to get desired result.